# Replace specific text without affecting styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Need to replace colons wherever they're found in specific elements with id's. This works but for some reason also replaces the styling attached to the elements:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
  $("#element").each(function () { //for element 
      var s=$(this).text(); //get text
       $(this).text(s.replace(/:/g, ' ')); //set text to the replaced version
  });
```

});

I tried attaching a class to the element but it made no difference. How do I just remove the colons without affecting anything else?
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webbrewers/cMGqH/)

Comment: what is the HTML code contained in #element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the HTML code in #element ?

If replacing the text in `#element` changes the style, it means that `#element` also contains some HTML tags (and the style is actually applied on those tags).

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#element").each(function () {
    (function trim_colons(el) {
      for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; ++i) {
          var c = el.childNodes[i];
          if (c.nodeType == 1) trim_colons(c);
          else if (c.nodeType == 3) c.nodeValue = c.nodeValue.replace(/:/g, ' ');
      }
    })(this);
  });
});
```

This will correctly remove `:` characters, without changing the style.

Comment: Ahh, that did the trick! I did try targeting just the text within the element but couldn't figure it out. Brillaint-thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the .html() method: http://api.jquery.com/html/

because according to this: http://api.jquery.com/text/

*it calls the DOM method .createTextNode(), which replaces special characters with their HTML entity equivalents (such as `&lt;` for `<`)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#element").each(function () { //for element 
      var s=$(this).html(); //get text
       $(this).html(s.replace(/:/g, ' ')); //set text to the replaced version
  });
});
```

Comment: It just _removes_ **escaping** by translating **entities** back to plain text, which is totally expected. On the other side, what is true is that `<tags>` are not returned (they are not text)

Comment: replacing `:` directly on HTML code may be dangerous; there can be `:` on namespaced tag names (`<fbml:something>`), attribute names (`<a ns:something="">`; or in attribute values (`<a href="http://...">`) for example ;-)

Comment: This works too-(and has the added advantage that I think understand why!) Thank you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately, this still strips the colon from html tags, like <img src-"http //........">.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you did'nt meant to have text in input types replaced ha!
For html elements other than input elements to fetch innerhtml you should use

```
var s=$(this).html();
```